# How to set kate as default for opening html files

Tags: default-programs

I am on kubuntu 14.04 LTS

I am unable to set kate as default application to open html files.

I have tried three GUI options:

1) right click > open with > others > kate > remember file type association

2) right click > properties > file type options > kate is at top

3) Ubuntu-Tweak

Everything shows like kate has been set as default application to open html files, but whenever i click on the html file, it opens with chrome.

Please help!

Edit1:

I also rebooted my laptop after each change, just to make sure it wasnt because of that

Comment: What does it say when you run `xdg-mime query default text/html` in a terminal?

Comment: it says: kate.desktop